# How to version control with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm looking for a way to control versions of my project through IntelliJ. However, I know Git can manage it the best way and I already did started experiencing Git with the help of [Madara Uchiha's Git tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgMqYboWydc). I must say it is incredibly useful, but I rather have version control arranged on my harddrive which is constantly backed up.

I decided doing my version control manually and it's pretty slow and annoying. Is there an easier and more efficient way to clone the current project files in another folder?

For example, clone the current project files on another folder named v1.4.2 outside my project structure without relocating my project files, also having them refactored as project on its own so they be runnable whenever.

Comment: Why don't you use Git on your local hard drive? You don't need to create any remote repository in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a local Git repository for the project. It will start with a master branch. Then create a working branch that you make your changes in. You can merge this branch back in to master as you are ready. You can create as many branches as you need and switch between them very quickly. All using the one directory.

If you are new to git you can use something like [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) - (a GUI for Git) it will allow you to manage the repository. It makes it really fast to switch between branches of your repository. It also helps with pushing changes to another location. GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.

For backup, you could always set up the project on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). You can create public and private repositories for free. I really recommend setting this part up.

Depending on the environment that you are building on, you could build a shell script / batch script that would copy files to the duplicate location. Without knowing what type of project you are developing in/for it is hard to say what would be the best strategy.

Ideally if your project has a build output you could have the compiler/IntelliJ IDEA place the results into your result folder. You could then copy the results to your Builds/v1.4.2 folder or wherever. Whether you check in the files that are built will depend on your project. You can always exclude files/folders like your ../Builds that you don't want to track via your *.gitignore* file.